# Three.js: object light & displacementMap

Tags: javascript, three.js, lighting

I'm trying to make a realistic silver ring like this:

[image: Desidered result]

with different colors and size.

This is my result at this moment:

[image: Result at this moment]

As you can see my ring is not smooth.
I don't know if it's a problem of the model, or of the code:

There are my models ( i'm using 2 model, one for the light silver and another for the dark one )

- light: http://www.websuvius.it/atma/myring/assets/3d/anello-1/interno.obj
- dark: http://www.websuvius.it/atma/myring/assets/3d/anello-1/esterno.obj

This is part of my code:

```
...

scene = new THREE.Scene();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, containerWidth / containerHeight, 0.1, 20000 );
scene.add(camera);
camera.position.set( 0, 150, 400 );
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
renderer.setClearColor( 0xf0f0f0 );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( containerWidth, containerHeight );

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.enableZoom = false;

var ambientlight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
scene.add( ambientlight );

var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {};
var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {};
var onError = function ( xhr ) {};

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );

loader.load( path + '/assets/3d/anello-1/interno.obj', function ( object ) {

    var backgroundTexture = textureLoader.load( path + '/assets/3d/texture/argento_standard_512_1024.jpg');

    backgroundTexture.flipY = false;

    var background = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: backgroundTexture,
        envMap: textureCube,
        reflectivity:0.5
    });

    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            child.material = background;
        }
    });

    object.position.y =-50;
    scene.add(object);

}, onProgress, onError );


loader.load( path + '/assets/3d/anello-1/esterno.obj', function ( object ) {

    var geometry = object.children[ 0 ].geometry;
    var materials = [];

    var scavoTexture = textureLoader.load( path + '/assets/3d/texture/argento_scuro_512_1024.jpg');


    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: scavoTexture,
        envMap: textureCube,
        reflectivity:0.5
    });

    materials.push(material);

    var customTexture = textureLoader.load( path + "/" + immagine);

    customTexture.flipY = false;

    var custom = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: customTexture,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 0xffffff
    }); 

    materials.push(custom);

    esterno = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry, materials);

    esterno.position.y=-50;

    scene.add(esterno);

}, onProgress, onError );


container = document.getElementById( 'preview3d' );

container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

animate();
```

How can i get a better result?
I have to change my models? My code? Both?
Thanks

[EDIT]

Thanks, everyone for the comments.
This is the result now:

[image: Ring with shade and textures]

Now, i have another question. Is there a way to extrude the text and other elements? I have only a png element of the central part.

Thanks

[EDIT 2]

Now I'm making some experiment with displacementMap.
This is the result at this moment:

[image: ring with displacement]

Now the problem is: the browser freeze due to heavily subdivided mesh.
This is a part of my code:

```
var external = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry( 3.48, 3.48, 4, 800, 400, true, -1.19, 5.54 );

var materials = [];

var baseMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x222222
});

materials.push(baseMaterial);

var textureMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: image, //PNG with text and symbols
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 1,
    reflectivity:0.5,
    color: 0xc0c0c0,
    emissive: 0x111111,
    specular: 0xffffff,
    shininess: 34,
    displacementMap: image, //same as map
    displacementScale: 0.15,
    displacementBias: 0
}); 

materials.push(textureMaterial);

var externalObj = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(external, materials);
```

I think that the problem is the 800x400 segments of cylinder, that generate a mesh with 320000 "faces". There is a way to optimize the performance keeping this level of detail?

Thanks again.

P.s. maybe I have to open a new question?

Comment: this has something to do the polygon count of ur object. smoothness of the 3D object with curve surface is largely determined by the polygon count.

Comment: You'll also want to look into reflections (https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_balls_reflection.html) and bump maps (https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_bumpmap.html). These two texturing concepts will help make the ring appear more realistic.

Comment: Maybe you need to add `shading: THREE.SmoothShading` to your material definitions.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. I've updated the question with a new image, and another question.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your new question: you could use your png also as displacement map. Have a look at the official example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_displacementmap.html
But you probably need to heavily subdivide your "central part" for displacement.

Maybe in your case there will be your png as bump map sufficient enough, then you you might check out this example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_bumpmap.html

Comment: Thanks! I've tested the replacement map, but to have a good result i have to subdivide the dark cylinder with 1000x500 segments and my browser freeze :D I'll continue to make experiment with displacement and bump maps

Comment: I would first try the bump map approach. Maybe this will already be enough. Alternatively, you could realize the text as extra 3d objects in your 3d program.
Displacement with sharp edges like in this case looks always a bit weird and results in a high cpu/gpu load. So I would try to avoid displacement. I forgot to mention this in my answer.

Comment: I tried with bump map approach, but it is not enough for my needs. I can't pre-build the text, because it is built dinamically from a web image editor ( based on canvas/fabricjs ).