# Threejs: displacement map and performance

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping

I'm opening a new question after editing this one: [Three.js: object light & displacementMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628253/three-js-object-light-displacementmap)

I have this ring:

[image: ring]

The dark part is generated with this code:

```
var external = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry( 3.48, 3.48, 4, 800, 400, true, -1.19, 5.54 );

var materials = [];

var baseMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x222222
});

materials.push(baseMaterial);

var textureMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: image, //PNG with text and symbols
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 1,
    reflectivity:0.5,
    color: 0xc0c0c0,
    emissive: 0x111111,
    specular: 0xffffff,
    shininess: 34,
    displacementMap: image, //same as map
    displacementScale: 0.15,
    displacementBias: 0
}); 

materials.push(textureMaterial);

var externalObj = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(external, materials);
```

The problem is that the browser and the computer freeze!

I think that the problem is the 800x400 segments of cylinder, that generates a mesh with 320000 "faces". Is there a way to optimize the performance keeping this level of detail?

Comment: Is your image Power of Two ? Recalculations on that many faces might cause fps drops (*although this is debatable and might be linked to a number of causes, I have experienced such a situation myself*).

To make sure the image you use isn't responsible for the perf issue, go and comment out the  `map` of your material and tell us what happens.

Comment: @Hesha sorry for the late answer. I commented all the map reference and the problem persists.